# How to save input in C# console application

Tags: c#, console-application

I need help about saving inputs in specified text file but I don't know how to create and save inputs in that file. So can someone help me about saveStudent function?

```
private static void addStudent()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Name: ");
            string ime = Console.ReadLine();

            Console.WriteLine("Lastname: ");
            string prezime = Console.ReadLine();

            Console.WriteLine("Subject: ");
            string kurs = Console.ReadLine();

            saveStudent();
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to save all the inputs into one string like

```
string Str = ime + prezime + kurs;
```

and then just

```
System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"C:\ConsoleInput.Txt",Str);
```

Or

```
string Str = ime + prezime + kurs;
saveStudent(Str);
```

In the saveStudent() Function

```
public string saveStudent(string s)
{
    System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"C:\ConsoleInput.Txt",Str); //You can choose your own path.
}
```